# Tagfield Cursor is not coming at current line

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

I am using tagfield and after selecting two or three values my curser moving to down. I want my cursor in same line even if a bit of space is there and after type or select any value then it move to down. Can anybody help me how to get this. 
I have specify the specific width also.

My Code :

```
{   xtype: Tagfield,
    growMax  : 10,
    valueField: 'title',
    displayField: 'title',
    parentGrid : me,
    queryMode: 'local',
    autoLoadOnValue:true, 
    multiSelect: true,
    isFilterDataLoaded: false,
    disabled: true,
    triggers: {
        clear: {
            weight: -30,
            cls: 'button-cross',
            handler: function(){
               this.clearValue();
            }
        }
    },
}
```

Here is my fiddler: [TagfieldFiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/20c8).
Step to reproduce :
1. Select three tags.
2. For fourth tag cursor is going to next line. I want cursoer should be in first line.

Comment: One specific reason for downvote. .

Answer (score 0):

You have to resize the input field according to the text that has been entered. Since the input field is an `Ext.dom.Element`, you will have to check that this works in all browsers:

```
listeners:{
    afterrender: function(tagfield) {
        var minWidth = 10, // modify here for adjustable text field width
            el = Ext.getBody().createChild(),
            measurer = new Ext.util.TextMetrics(el);
        tagfield.inputEl.setWidth(minWidth);
        tagfield.inputEl.on('keyup', function() {
            var requiredWidth = measurer.getWidth(tagfield.inputEl.dom.value);
            tagfield.inputEl.setWidth(requiredWidth+minWidth);
        });
        tagfield.on('change', function() {
            var requiredWidth = measurer.getWidth(tagfield.inputEl.dom.value);
            tagfield.inputEl.setWidth(requiredWidth+minWidth);
        });
    }
}
```

Try it here: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/20cb

I have changed the ExtJS version because there seems to be a bug in tag field in ExtJS 6.0 - if you enter through keyboard, the content of the input is not removed after selection.

Comment: This answer is fantastic, but I can not resize my tag field because  I am using it as widget on grid column so I given ` growMax  : 10,` as well. Well I will try to modify as much I can. Thanks

Comment: And when I modified as per your answer as per my requirement I got the same answer, https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/20cf

Comment: My answer is not resizing the tag field, it is resizing the input element. That's helluva difference.